# Where and how is the password stored for the account associated with a Windows service?

Tags: windows, security, windows-registry

In HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MY-SERVICE-NAME there is the `Object Name` key which contains the name of the user, but I can not find the password.

I am trying to understand how DP API interacts with Windows services management and with the service process itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passwords for Windows services are stored in the registry under:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\_SC_<ServiceName>`

When you configure a Windows service to run as a different account, the Service Control Manager uses the `LsaStorePrivateData` function to store the password, and the corresponding `LsaRetrievePrivateData` function to retrieve it.

So it is reversible encryption of some kind, but sorry, the exact encryption algorithm and technique are not publically documented. And helping you further reverse engineer it would be fun, but not a good idea for me.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note: the default registry permission will not allow you to list the content of  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY` and it will look empty. For educational purpose you can update the permission and allow full right to the administrators. Based on your information I also found this page http://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=23

Comment: I also found this post http://moyix.blogspot.ro/2008/02/decrypting-lsa-secrets.html

Comment: ps. if anyone's still using windows 2000 (we have one legacy system which still does!) and wants to run a process under the system account, the current version of psexec doesn't seem to work. However the windows scheduler (`at` command) can be used: https://verbalprocessor.com/2007/12/05/running-a-cmd-prompt-as-local-system/

Answer (score 3):

While the actual encryption method may not be clear, accessing the data and requesting that the OS decrypt it on your behalf is a well-defined process - using [PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/06/use-powershell-to-decrypt-lsa-secrets-from-the-registry/) or [the NirSoft LSASecretsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/lsa_secrets_view.html) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this page when looking for the `ADSync` password for Azure AD Connect service.

For anyone else, to change the `NT SERVICE\ADSync` password, follow this guide as it's not straightforward:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-change-serviceacct-pass